# Emacs Erlang mode indenting twice what erlang-indent-level specifies

Tags: emacs, erlang, indentation, emacs23

Emacs is indenting my Erlang twice as much as I think I'm telling it to.

If I set erlang-indent-level to 2, it indents to 4:

```
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) ->
    lists:sum(Values)
end.
```

If I set erlang-indent-level to 4, it indents to 8:

```
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) ->
        lists:sum(Values)
end
```

I've verified, using "od -c", that there are no tab characters in my Erlang files.

Why is the indentation level twice what erlang-indent-level is set to?

---

The parts of my .emacs having to do with indentation:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(indent-tabs-mode nil)
 ...

; Set to 2 in order to get 4
(setq erlang-indent-level 2)
```

Versions:

- GNU Emacs 23.2.1
- erlang.el from Debian package "erlang-mode" version 1:14.a-dfsg-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because "fun" is a special keyword. If you name your function to something else, it will indent the function as you expect.

Comment: Lambdas get indented twice?  Wow.  I never would have guessed it.

Comment: Well, that's how I choosed to implement in in erlang.el. Glad to see that there still are people around using it!

Comment: Oh, I wasn't saying it's a bad choice.  It just caught me by surprise.  erlang.el seems to work great--Thanks for your contribution, and this answer.

Comment: You're welcome! (Btw, talk about timing, I just started using S.O. this week...)

Comment: Personally, I would prefer it to indent to just `erlang-indent-level`. I don't see the point of the double indent and everything wanders off to the right very quickly.

Comment: Robert? Long time no see! As I've been away from the Erlang world for the last fifteen years, I can't remember why the indentation became the way it is. I think it was because some constructs would look wrong if the extra indentation level would not be there, but maybe it could be possible to find a good compromise -- Anders

Comment: @Lindydancer Perhaps adding a defcustom variable that control this behaviour?

Comment: @PRouleau, the main question is if it's normal Erlang to use a keyword to name functions. In that case you will have to contact whoever maintains the code (I haven't worked on it for 20+ years). On the other hand, if it's not, then it would be better if Erlang itself would issue an error or warning.

Comment: @Lindydancer, I believe it's invalid Erlang to use the `fun` keyword for a function name.   But it's expected to have something like `F = fun(A) -> A+42.` I looked at the erlang.el briefly and I saw one spot where the impact of the doubled comment is but at this point I don't know what the impact of this code is.  If the `fun` (the anonymous function) has several lines, it's possible to write comments inside it.   See https://learnyousomeerlang.com/higher-order-functions#anonymous-functions